# how to get all header information in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to get all header information from a laravel request in API I have tried few packages and [this](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker) one is really worth a shot but I want to store these information (not all of them) I want information like users lat long, device information to track them and get info regarding my app performance for different devices and then store them into my own migrated tables I have designed a table statistics for that but I don't know how to get all these information and then store in it

any help from you people?

Comment: Have you tried Google analytics ?

Comment: nope enlighten me please?

Comment: If you're looking for statistics about your users, (e.g. locations, devices used, or even how long time a user spent on a page). Google analytics is the best for this. You just register your website and a small code to your html, and then you get real time data about your visitors.

Comment: yes I want such stats. on each request of my api. is there any good package that you would recommend?

Comment: You don't need any package for this. Just register at https://analytics.google.com and follow the instructions.